# I faced an error said 'Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name. '

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

this is my urls.py

```
path('login/', views.login, name="login"),
path('signOut/', views.signOut, name= "signOut"),
```

these are my views, I replaced 'login' in the signOut function with 'home' but I still have the same error.

```
def login (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request , username = username ,password = password)
        if user is not None:
            dj_login(request, user)
            return redirect ('home')    
    context= {}
    return render (request , 'freelancing_app/login.html' ,context )


def signOut (request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Seems fine unless your folder structure is incorrect. Please specify app names and their files.

Comment: Can you share your url tree, with the project `urls.py` that includes your app `urls.py`?

Comment: Do you have `app_name` in your `urls.py`? For example, if you had `app_name = 'auth'`, then you would use `redirect('auth:login')`.

Comment: Note that Django comes with [authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) including `LoginView` and `LogoutView`. It might be easier and safer to use them than to write your own.

Comment: I have only one app named 'freelancing_app' , which contains several directories and files, in general it has an independent urls file in the same directory of the views, the templates are in a folder in the project root directory.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('freelancing_app.urls'))
]
this is the urls.py file of the project

Comment: @Alasdair
Thanks alot sir!
your solution worked, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to add the app name followed with a colon before the desired view which I want to redirect my current view to.
in my case; my app name is 'freelancing_app', the code below shows the answer:

```
def signOut (request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('freelancing_app:login')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change code as below:

Instead of redirect you can use render function.

def signOut (request):

```
logout(request)
return render(request,'login.html')
```